# Creating 2-d Ising Model

Tags: rule, graphics

```
size = 50;
Clear[s];
hot[seed_] := Module[{}, RandomSeed[seed];
  Table[If[RandomInteger[] ⩵ 0, 1, -1], {i, 1, size}, {j, 1, size}]]
cold[m_] := Table[Sign[m], {i, 1, size}, {j, 1, size}]
s = hot[123];
plotIsing := 
  ListDensityPlot[s, Mesh \[RightArrow] False, 
   InterpolationOrder \[RightArrow] 0, 
   PlotRange \[RightArrow] {-1, 1}];
plotIsing
```

Hello, this is my attempt to create a grph of 2-D ising Modle.
However, I get an error message

```
ListDensityPlot::nonopt: Options expected (instead of PlotRange\[RightArrow]{-1,1}) beyond position 1 in ListDensityPlot[<<1>>]. An option must be a rule or a list of rules.
```

I replaced the "RightArrow" to "Rule", but my Mathematica automatically change "Rule" to "Rightarrow".
What should I do to resolve this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't know why `\[Rule]` would be replaced by `\[RightArrow]`, but as an immediate workaround (and typically what I type) use `-` followed by `>`. When you enter a space afterward, the front end should replace it with `\[Rule]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
ListDensityPlot[s, Mesh -> None, InterpolationOrder -> 0, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}]
```

[image]